# How to get all guest users count in M365 groups with Microsoft graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, odata

I tried to get all guest users count in all M365 groups in single Microsoft graph api call I have written below query for that.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=memberOf($filter=groupTypes/any(c:c eq 'unified'))&$filter=userType eq 'Guest'&$Count=true
```

it looks like nested query inside memberof is not filtering group. Any help or suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say that the query inside memberOf is not filtering group, do you mean that the filter expression `$filter=groupTypes/any(c:c eq 'unified')` is not applied to the expanded memberOf collection navigation property or that it's not applied to users?

Comment: Thanks for response. The filter expression i.e. $filter=groupTypes/any(c:c eq 'unified') is not getting applied on expanded memberOf collection navigation property.filter on user is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To review all guest users assigned to all Microsoft 365 groups , please use the below query, refer this [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/accessreviews-scope-concept#example-5-review-all-guest-users-assigned-to-all-microsoft-365-groups).

```
"instanceEnumerationScope": {
    "query": "/groups?$filter=(groupTypes/any(c:c eq 'Unified'))",
    "queryType": "MicrosoftGraph"
},
"scope": {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.accessReviewQueryScope",
    "query": "./members/microsoft.graph.user/?$filter=(userType eq 'Guest')",
    "queryType": "MicrosoftGraph"
}
```

Please also check the group search limitations for guest users in organizations, refer this [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/users?view=graph-rest-1.0#user-and-group-search-limitations-for-guest-users-in-organizations).

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Hi Mehtab Thanks for reply. I simply want the count of distinct guest users that belongs to any m365 groups.